# HC-05 and HC-06 Bluetooth not communicating well

Tags: bluetooth, softwareserial

I am trying to communicate between two Arduino UNO. One has a HC-05 which is configured as master, the other Arduino has HC-06 which is the slave. What I want to achieve is to be able to print a character on the Serial monitor of the slave Arduino when a button on the master Arduino is pressed. I have been able to pair the two and once they are powered, they connect automatically. When I press a button on the master, what I get on the serial monitor of the slave is the 254 instead of the character 'a' which is what I am sending from the master. I have tried changing the data type, and also switched the code for master and slave, but the problem persists. I have also used hardware serial instead of software serial. My HC-05, and HC-06 works well when paired with android phone and can send and receive useful data. My code is as shown below:

CODE FOR MASTER:(SENDER)

```cpp
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
const int rxPin = 10;
const int txPin = 11;
const int button = 2;

SoftwareSerial masterSerial(rxPin,txPin);//RX,TX.

void setup() {
   pinMode(button, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   masterSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

   int buttonVal = digitalRead(button);
   if(buttonVal==HIGH){
       masterSerial.write('a');
      delay(1000);
   }
//mySerial.flush();
}
```

---

CODE FOR SLAVE( RECEIVER)

```cpp
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

const int rxPin = 10;
const int txPin = 11;

int incomingByte = 0;

SoftwareSerial slaveSerial(rxPin,txPin);//RX,TX.

void setup() {

   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   slaveSerial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

   while(slaveSerial.available()){
      incomingByte = slaveSerial.read();
      delay(3);
      Serial.println(incomingByte);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone solved?